# SELECT and INNER JOIN inside WHERE IN ()

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete, sql-limit

I need to do something like this

```
DELETE FROM order 
WHERE id IN  (  SELECT order.id 
            FROM db.order 
            INNER JOIN db.product ON product.id = order.product_id
            WHERE product.date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 YEAR)) LIMIT 10000);
```

However that doesnt work. is there a way I can do this, or maybe a different way? I do need to delete data older than 6 years old, so if there is another way im happy trying it.

Comment: LIMIT 10000? You can't pass 10000 references in the IN clause. You have to use a join on a temporary table for this kind of query. IN handles the situation where you have more than one but few items

Comment: @LelioFaieta what about if the Limit to 10000 is outside WHERE IN?

Comment: the point is: "how many records are returned inside the IN clause". And the LIMIT is inside the IN in your code so that's not the point

Comment: @LelioFaieta I dont understand the point you trying to make sorry. the limit is there because there is too much data to be deleted it needs to be run periodically.

Comment: You say "that doesnt seem to work". What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner maybe i should just say it doesnt work :D it just doesnt work throws error

Comment: @luke, limit clause in your query is in the wrong place to be applied to delete. Must be outside the `()` to be applied to delete. This way it applies to the inner SELECT

Comment: It throws errors? Which? Error messages are usually meant to point you to the problem. Why do you keep the message you are getting a secret?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner here is the error big man you happy now   `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'order' for update in FROM clause `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql does not support `LIMIT` for multi-table `DELETE` statements, so what you can do is apply limit in a subquery and then join to `order`:

```
DELETE o 
FROM `order` o 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT o.id FROM `order` o INNER JOIN product p 
  ON p.product_id = o.id
  WHERE p.date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 YEAR)) 
  LIMIT 10000
) t ON t.id = o.id;
```

Comment: Thanks that sounds what i need im just trying to run it now its throwing some error.

Comment: @Luke what is the error? The query is syntactically correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39f46692dcdfc8302e20e0251c67a1b2

Comment: got it working thanks :)

the error was just a miss placed table name, the table name above is not actually the table name in the product for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

To DELETE with JOINS you use aliases to target the table where the deletion should take place. I think you can find in the docs, but the syntax is:

```
DELETE o FROM
  order AS o
JOIN
  product AS p ON
    product.id = order.product_id
    AND product.date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 YEAR))
```

This would delete only records from the order-table.

Doc : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Look for "Multi-Table Deletes"

Not sure what you want to do with the limit 10000 though, but like Lelio Faieta suggested, you can use a subquery for that:

```
DELETE o FROM
  order AS o
JOIN
  (SELECT o.id
  FROM order
  JOIN
    product AS p ON
      product.id = order.product_id
      AND product.date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 YEAR))
  LIMIT 10000
  ) AS s ON s.id = o.id
```

Comment: thank you im trying to execute it right now :)

Comment: will not work ... sorry ... Lelio Faieta is right about the limit ... and my syntax is not correct ... didn't see that last part of your query

Comment: By the way ... hope you checked with a SELECT first of the result is really what you want to throw away ;)

Comment: thanks for the help, I really need that LIMIT tho thats what is messing me up :(

Comment: the limit is because some tables i have contains over 20 mil records that are older than 6 years old. removing it entirely will slow down the db alot, its not just one table its many. there is a cron job that will be running periodically

Comment: in that case it might be easier to create a duplicate table of order, INSERT the records you DO want in the duplicate and then throw away the original table

Comment: That wont work its not up to me in the first place :D and its too many tables would be alot more working doing that way i think